# Сервер Qt вылетает с ошибкой ASSERT: "!isEmpty()" in file ..\..\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h, line 344

Tags: c++, qt, сокет, qt5, qtcpsocket

При загрузке файла сервером с клиента на java сервер вылетает с ошибками:

```
ASSERT: "!isEmpty()" in file ..\..\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h, line 344
ASSERT: "!isEmpty()" in file ..\..\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h, line 348
```

Интересно, что когда все это работало в основном потоке, не вылетало. Краткий код:

```
/*tcpservthread.h ну это очень кратко там еще много моего быдлокода*/
    class TcpServThread: public QThread
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    private:
        int keyFiles = 0;   
        bool writefilepr = false;
        QFile* rfile;
        ResponseFileObj* rfo = 0;
        QTcpSocket* pClientSocket;
   public slots:
       void slotReadClient   ();


}
/*tcpservthread.cpp*/

TcpServThread::TcpServThread(qintptr ID, QObject *parent):
    QThread(parent)
{
    this->socketDescriptor = ID;
}
void TcpServThread::run()
{
    pClientSocket = new QTcpSocket();
    if(!pClientSocket->setSocketDescriptor(this->socketDescriptor))
    {
        return;
    }
connect(pClientSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()),pClientSocket, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(pClientSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()),this, SLOT(sldiconnected()));
    connect(pClientSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(slotReadClient()));
    connect (pClientSocket,SIGNAL(error (QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),this,SLOT (slotSocketError (QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
exec();
}
void TcpServThread::slotReadClient()
{
//Эту переменную обнулим когда файл полностью прочитаем по ней ориентируемся 
//что нам делать если twobytes==0 то значит мы не закончили с определенной 
// командой например загр файла
if(twobytes==0) { 
        float ltwobytes;
        int lsixbytes;
        if(readFirstInfo(ltwobytes, lsixbytes)) {
            twobytes = ltwobytes;
            sixbytes = lsixbytes;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
if(twobytes == COM_LOAD_FILE) { 
   int avaib = pClientSocket->bytesAvailable();
        if(avaib==0 || avaib<0) {
            return;
        }
        //Смотрим есть ли у нас список файлов вобьекте, нет парсим

        if(!rfo) {
            QString infostr = readMainStr(false);
            qDebug() <<"twobites|sixbytes" <<twobytes <<sixbytes;
            if(infostr=="") {
                return;
            }
            rfo = parseToCl(infostr);

        }
int fsize = rfo->files.size();
        //Вот в этом цикле и происходит загрузка файла с клиента,
    //но в нем пока 1 единственный файл и все это вылетает с ошибкой
    //наверное я делаю что то не так 
        //MFile - обьект с информацией по загружаемому файлу
    //keyFile ключ который я сохраняю чтобы не проходить список загр. файлов с самого начала 
        for(int i= keyFiles; i<fsize; i++) {
            MFile file = rfo->files[i];
            avaib = pClientSocket->bytesAvailable();
            if(file.isDirectory()) {
                // //тут оперции по созданию папок не буду приводить будем считать что это 1 файл
            } else {
                if(avaib == 0) {
                    keyFiles = i;
                    break;
                }
                //сперва глянем писался ли файл
                if(writefilepr) {
                   //да он писался
                } else {
                    rfile = new QFile(file.getAbsolutePuth());
                    if(!rfile->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){qDebug() << "Ошибка открытия для записи";}
                    writefilepr = true;
                }
                long msize=0;
                //Сколько байтов записало
                if(writingBytes>0) {
                    msize = file.length()-writingBytes;
                } else {
                    msize = file.length();
                }
                if(avaib > msize || avaib == msize) {
                    qDebug() <<"iatyt1";
                    QByteArray b = pClientSocket->read(msize);
                    rfile->write(b);
                    rfile->close();
                    writingBytes = 0;
                    writefilepr = false;
                    qDebug() <<"iatyt2";
                    continue;
                } else {
                    qDebug() <<"iatyt3";
                    QByteArray b = pClientSocket->read(avaib);
                    rfile->write(b);
                    writingBytes += avaib;
                    keyFiles = i;
                    qDebug() <<"writebytes=" <<writingBytes <<"|keyFiles="<<keyFiles <<"file.size=" << file.length();
                    qDebug() <<"iatyt4";
                    break;
                }
            }
}
}
```

Там было немного сложнее, но я решил переписать, чтобы вычислить ошибку - результат тот же самый - вылетает.

Comment: Запустите проект в режиме отладки, чтобы выполнение остановилось на этом assert-е, после чего перейдите в обозреватель стека функций и ищите причину проблемы там.

Comment: Именно этот assert [срабатывает при попытке работы с элементами пустого списка](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dd613e65eaa4863ba987eb5e9efeff54d25cdd63/src/corelib/tools/qlist.h#L345-L352). Могу предположить, что возникает проблема межпоточной синхронизации чтения из списка и записи в него (раз при помещении всего в главный поток всё работает).

Comment: А вы можете если не сложно пожалуйста поподробней? Обозреватель стека функций это вкладка стек? Я в дебаге (F5)  смотрю, Оно у меня бывает в приложении список: ASSERT: "!isEmpty()" in file ..\..\include/... выводит и вкладка стек пустая. Бывает стек срабатывает. А бывает что приложение ложиться вместе с QT Creator. Еще заметил по выводу что очень медленно работает и очень часто bytesAvailable == 0

Comment: Если дело под linux, то запустите в консоли, перед этим дав команду `ulimit -c unlimited` и после падения спокойно анализируйте `core` в отладчике.

Comment: Типичная ошибка совместного доступа к общим ресурсам, в данном случае к списку. Один поток читает элементы из списка, другой изменяет их количество. И если вам не повезет (а вам не повезет 100%), вы одним потоком обнулите количество элементов в общем списке, в тот же момент как второй только только возьмет вилочку и ножик, чтобы поработать с каким-либо их элементов. Чтобы избежать подобного рада проблем нужно защитить общий код мьютексом

Comment: Мне кажется, но проблема в том, что когда вы создаете pClientSocket, то это явный сокет без родителя и это означает, что сам сокет создается в том потоке в каком вы хотите.

Answer (score 1):

Раз QList не используется в исходном коде, тогда значит он где-то в Qt классах внутри используется и как-то косвенно приводит к ошибке. Ошибка означает что QList оказался пустым когда вызвали операцию, которой нужно чтобы был хотя бы один элемент (например метод first() для получения первого элемента), вот список всех методов QList который могут подобную ошибку выдать - first(), last(), removeFirst(), removeLast(). Кстати, нужно проверить есть ли где-то в вашем коде использование этих методов у QList, если нет значит нужно проверять какой код косвенно вызывает эти методы. Если есть желание и возможность перекомпилировать Qt для решения подобных задач, тогда можно в исходниках кюти в файле \qtbase\src\corelib\global\qglobal.cpp поправить функцию qt_assert (именно она вызывается при Q_ASSERT), добавив стэк вызова в этот момент (чтобы узнать что приводит к вызову методов QList ведущих к ошибке). Чтобы вывести стэк можно воспользоваться [Boost StackTrace](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/stacktrace.html), т.к. вроде в С++ стандартной библиотеке ничего подходящего для этого нет. Выводить можно с помощью qFatal(), пример использования его есть как раз в qt_assert функции. Только нужно убедиться что Qt компилируется в дебаг версии т.к. только в ней срабатывает Q_ASSERT, либо нужно при компиляции включить дефайн QT_FORCE_ASSERTS.